# What does a reputation deduction with the description “User was removed” mean?

Tags: support, moderation

I noticed this in my account this morning, and I would like to know what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some explanation of that here, on the main Meta-site -- [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/139866)

There's also a Help topic on the subject -- [Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says 'User was removed'?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed)

Comment: Thank you, Chris.

Comment: You're welcome. Would you "Accept" this answer? Because otherwise it will keep bubbling to the top of the Active list as an "Unanswered question" in future.